# Azure File Rest API Create Directory Fails Authentication but List Directory works

Tags: c#, azure, azure-files

So i am having an issue with the Azure Rest API for creating directories and files. I can list directories and files, which uses the same method to create the Authorization header, but i always get the 403 - Server failed to authenticate the request. The first block of code below is the code to obtain a list of directories which works.

```
String uri = string.Format($"https://{_azureClientSettings.StorageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net/{_azureClientSettings.StorageShare}?restype=directory&comp=list");

                // Set this to whatever payload you desire. Mine is null because i'm not passing anything in.
                Byte[] requestPayload = null;

                //Instantiate the request message with a null payload.
                using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri)
                { Content = (requestPayload == null) ? null : new ByteArrayContent(requestPayload) })
                {

                    // Add the request headers for x-ms-date and x-ms-version.
                    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");

                    // Add the authorization header.
                    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(
                       _azureClientSettings.StorageAccountName, _azureClientSettings.StorageAccountKey, now, httpRequestMessage);

                    // Send the request.
                    using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await _httpClientRepo.Instance().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken.None))
                    {
                        if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This block of code is the code i use in an attempt to create a directory, which fails.

```
Uri storageUri = new Uri($"https://{_azureClientSettings.StorageAccountName}.file.core.windows.net/{_azureClientSettings.StorageShare}/{directoryName}?restype=directory");

using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, storageUri)
{ Content = new StringContent("") })
{
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-content-length", "200");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-type", "file");

                // Add the authorization header.
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(
                    _azureClientSettings.StorageAccountName, _azureClientSettings.StorageAccountKey, now, httpRequestMessage);

                // Send the request.
                using (var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClientRepo.Instance().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, CancellationToken.None))
            {
               ...
            }
}
```

As i say, i have a very similar method for creating a file and that also fails with a 403.I have taken the authorization header creation from https://github.com/mstaples84/azurefileserviceauth/blob/4bce5c268cd9ce6c91d9e8723ce72eb5e0df3255/SimpleAzureFileServiceDemo/AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.cs

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you specifying `x-ms-content-length` request header? Also, you don't need `x-ms-type` header. Please see the REST API documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-directory.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you not using the SDK and implementing REST API directly?

Comment: I used it initially as i thought you couldn't use the SDK with files, only to find out your can. So i am looking at that now  in case i didn't have joy here. It is also one of those where by i would really like to know why it works one way and not the other, even if i do move to the SDK.

Comment: I didn't have those 2 headers initially and didn't work without them.

Comment: I just took your code and ran it. It worked for me and I was able to create a directory. Can you trace the request through a tool like Fiddler. You should see more error details in the response body. Please edit your question and paste that error message there.

Comment: Here's the code I wrote: https://gist.github.com/gmantri-ais/408df281f2a07802924cfa61a93379eb.

Comment: This is what comes back on the content, i have substituted the account and sahre names - The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'UELOj1sGUFfjmZWFZShePLHb/rtpwtc/5NPOyfUj8XU=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT\n\n\n\n\ntext/plain; charset=utf-8\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-content-length:200\nx-ms-date:Wed, 19 Feb 2020 10:29:04 GMT\nx-ms-type:file\nx-ms-version:2017-04-17\n/<account>/<share>/<directoryname>\nrestype:directory'.

Comment: For some reason AureStorageAuthenticationHelper is different to the one i had. i have changed it and it now works. I must have copied from elsewhere or had an old version. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @GauravMantri, can you post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, there was an issue with the code in `AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper`.

Here's the code I wrote that worked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Web;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string accountName = "myaccountname";
        const string accountKey = "myaccountkey";
        const string shareName = "test";
        const string directory = "test";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri storageUri = new Uri($"https://{accountName}.file.core.windows.net/{shareName}/{directory}?restype=directory");

            using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, storageUri)
            { Content = new StringContent("") })
            {
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2017-04-17");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-content-length", "200");
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("x-ms-type", "file");

                // Add the authorization header.
                httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper.GetAuthorizationHeader(
                    accountName, accountKey, now, httpRequestMessage);

                // Send the request.
                using (var response = new HttpClient().SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Directory created successfully.");
                }
            }

        }
    }

    internal static class AzureStorageAuthenticationHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This creates the authorization header. This is required, and must be built 
        ///   exactly following the instructions. This will return the authorization header
        ///   for most storage service calls.
        /// Create a string of the message signature and then encrypt it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="storageAccountName">The name of the storage account to use.</param>
        /// <param name="storageAccountKey">The access key for the storage account to be used.</param>
        /// <param name="now">Date/Time stamp for now.</param>
        /// <param name="httpRequestMessage">The HttpWebRequest that needs an auth header.</param>
        /// <param name="ifMatch">Provide an eTag, and it will only make changes
        /// to a blob if the current eTag matches, to ensure you don't overwrite someone else's changes.</param>
        /// <param name="md5">Provide the md5 and it will check and make sure it matches the blob's md5.
        /// If it doesn't match, it won't return a value.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal static AuthenticationHeaderValue GetAuthorizationHeader(
           string storageAccountName, string storageAccountKey, DateTime now,
           HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, string ifMatch = "", string md5 = "")
        {
            // This is the raw representation of the message signature.
            var method = httpRequestMessage.Method;

            // content length
            var contentLength = string.Empty;
            if (!(method == HttpMethod.Get || method == HttpMethod.Head))
            {
                var length = httpRequestMessage.Content?.Headers.ContentLength;

                if (length != null && length > 0)
                {
                    contentLength = length.ToString();
                }
            }

            String messageSignature = String.Format("{0}\n\n\n{1}\n{5}\n{7}\n{6}\n\n{2}\n\n\n\n{3}{4}",
                      method.ToString().ToUpper(),
                      contentLength,
                      ifMatch,
                      GetCanonicalizedHeaders(httpRequestMessage),
                      GetCanonicalizedResource(httpRequestMessage.RequestUri, storageAccountName),
                      md5,
                      string.Empty,
                      httpRequestMessage.Content?.Headers.ContentType.ToString() ?? string.Empty);

            // Now turn it into a byte array.
            var signatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageSignature);

            // Create the HMACSHA256 version of the storage key.
            var SHA256 = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(storageAccountKey));

            // Compute the hash of the SignatureBytes and convert it to a base64 string.
            var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.ComputeHash(signatureBytes));

            // This is the actual header that will be added to the list of request headers.
            // You can stop the code here and look at the value of 'authHV' before it is returned.
            var authHV = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("SharedKey",
                storageAccountName + ":" + signature);
            return authHV;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Put the headers that start with x-ms in a list and sort them.
        /// Then format them into a string of [key:value\n] values concatenated into one string.
        /// (Canonicalized Headers = headers where the format is standardized).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="httpRequestMessage">The request that will be made to the storage service.</param>
        /// <returns>Error message; blank if okay.</returns>
        private static string GetCanonicalizedHeaders(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
        {
            var headers = from kvp in httpRequestMessage.Headers
                          where kvp.Key.StartsWith("x-ms-", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                          orderby kvp.Key
                          select new { Key = kvp.Key.ToLowerInvariant(), kvp.Value };

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Create the string in the right format; this is what makes the headers "canonicalized" --
            //   it means put in a standard format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization
            foreach (var kvp in headers)
            {
                StringBuilder headerBuilder = new StringBuilder(kvp.Key);
                char separator = ':';

                // Get the value for each header, strip out \r\n if found, then append it with the key.
                foreach (string headerValues in kvp.Value)
                {
                    string trimmedValue = headerValues.TrimStart().Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
                    headerBuilder.Append(separator).Append(trimmedValue);

                    // Set this to a comma; this will only be used 
                    //   if there are multiple values for one of the headers.
                    separator = ',';
                }
                sb.Append(headerBuilder.ToString()).Append("\n");
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This part of the signature string represents the storage account 
        ///   targeted by the request. Will also include any additional query parameters/values.
        /// For ListContainers, this will return something like this:
        ///   /storageaccountname/\ncomp:list
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="address">The URI of the storage service.</param>
        /// <param name="accountName">The storage account name.</param>
        /// <returns>String representing the canonicalized resource.</returns>
        private static string GetCanonicalizedResource(Uri address, string storageAccountName)
        {
            // The absolute path is "/" because for we're getting a list of containers.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/").Append(storageAccountName).Append(address.AbsolutePath);

            // Address.Query is the resource, such as "?comp=list".
            // This ends up with a NameValueCollection with 1 entry having key=comp, value=list.
            // It will have more entries if you have more query parameters.
            NameValueCollection values = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(address.Query);

            foreach (var item in values.AllKeys.OrderBy(k => k))
            {
                sb.Append('\n').Append(item).Append(':').Append(values[item]);
            }

            return sb.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```